# How to present view controller modally when pressed tab bar in Swift or Storyboard?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to show the view controller modally when I pressed the middle tab bar. I try to pick "over the screen" on presentation style, it work like modal but the transition style is not like the modal presentation.

Sorry I'm new in iOS. I need a custom tab bar tutorial that can show a view controller modally, I can't find it...

The layout similar like this:[How to create tabbar with custom UI in swift 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367219/how-to-create-tabbar-with-custom-ui-in-swift-3-0)

but can I do that without framework? because quite complicated for me..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For presenting viewController

```
self.present(ClassToPePresented(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For Pushing viewController

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(ClassToPePushed(), animated: true)
```

Modify class name as requirement